# Can I make Vim filter entered ex commands?

Tags: vim

I know that this is probably better to solve by not typing sloppily in the first place, but I just think it would be really nice to have.

Since I've used Vim for a while, the `;w` (I have mapped normal mode `;` to `:`) is a bit of a reflex for me. However, what I dont like is that sometimes i type fast and that causes bad things to happen.

Take a look at my vimrc...

```
"""" Commenting out cmaps because cmap applies when e.g. typing in (/)-search mode
" " prevent common typos from actually writing files to disk
" cmap wq1 wq!
" cmap w1 w!
" cmap q1 q!
" cmap qa1 qa!
" cmap e1 e!
"
" cmap w; w
"
" cmap qw wq
" cmap qw! wq!
" cmap qw1 wq!
"
" " and more combinatorially exploding goodness for dealing with flubbing the
" " enter key
" cmap wq\ wq
" cmap wq1\ wq!
" cmap wq!\ wq!
" cmap w\ w
" cmap w1\ w!
" cmap w!\ w!
```

This goes on for 50 or so more lines.

They're all commented because `cmap` applies when using `/` to search. That's a dealbreaker.

And this doesnt even cover the cases where I write `:w` and then happen to mash some special char after it, and this somehow causes vim to write the buffer into a file named after that character. Great way to lose some work.

Any ideas? This is gonna require me to edit vim source code isn't it...

Comment: Sloppy typing is the issue, here: don't look for workarounds, fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the downside of `:cmap` is that it applies to all command-line modes, so it prevents you from searching for those strings, too.

One solution is to check the *type* of command-line mode, via an expression mapping:

```
cnoremap <expr> w1 getcmdtype() == ':' ? 'w!' : 'w1'
```

If you're clever, you can do meta-programming and define all your mappings in a loop, just passing in the source and target strings.

Even those modified mappings still don't allow you to type those mapped strings, e.g. as command arguments (so you can't easily `:w w1`, only by escaping the latter via `<C-V>`), though.

#### Plugin

The [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) plugin also checks the command position and therefore handles arguments. It also offers a convenient `:Alias` command, so you don't need to do metaprogramming.